# Javascript function ordering.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 functions in my javascript code. I want to call the 3rd function as soon as both function1 and function2 are over executing.

```
func_one();
func_two();

func_three();  // To be called as soon both of the above functions finish executing.
```

Note that they may take variable time since function 1 and 2 are for fetching geolocation and some ajax request respectively.

Comment: you will have to provide more details on what the functions contain? if its ajax calls then you can simply call the func_three() within the ajax success method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
func_one() {
    // Do something
    func_two();
}

func_two() {
    // Do something
    func_three();
}

func_three() {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Since he said he has ajax calls inside the function which are async This logic will not work

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.The first one is to create callback functions as parameters for your existing functions.

```
function one(param_1 .. param_n, callback) {
    var response = ... // some logic
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback(response);
    }
}
```

The second way is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise%22Promises%22) like:

```
var p1 = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
        var response = ... //some logic
        resolve(response);
    }
} 

var p2 = new Promise( ... );

p1.then(function(response1) {
    p2.then(function(response2) {
          //do some logic
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
var oneFinish = false;
var twoFinish = false;

function one(){
    //...
    oneFinish = true; // this value may depends on some logic
}

function two(){
    //...
    twoFinish = true; // this value may depends on some logic
}

function three(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if(oneFinish && twoFinish){
            //...
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your functions `func_one` and `func_two` are making service calls you can call the functions on after other at the success callback of the previous function. Like

```
   func_one().success(function(){
       func_two().success(function(){
           func_three();
       });
   });
```